# updating inbox new message count

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services

For one of my projects I needed to create a sort of internal email system. In my navigation menu at the top of the page I have a link to the inbox and that link also has the number of unread message.

Currently if you receive a new message the unread message count in the navigation isn't updated until the page is refreshed. This needs to change to so that it updates every few seconds on its own.

I don't want to use something premade, I want to create the solution myself but I just need a push in the right direction.

Should I use some sort of combination of ajax and webservices? Something else? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to use a combination of ajax and web services. Make an ajax method that fires off every few seconds and hits a web service endpoint which returns the number of unread messages in the inbox. Then have the ajax return method update the undread message count with the result from the server.

Comment: Just to clarify that web service in this context does not mean explicitly a .net soap web service.  You can have your ajax methods call a soap web service, page method, mvc controller action, wcf service method, and probably other apis too.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend having a look at `SignalR`. It's a freely available library that allows JavaScript to 'communicate' with C#, and vice versa, by keeping a connection active between the client and the server. It essentially means that upon someone sending a message, you trigger an event which then potentially 'pushes' a notification to the client, the client then checks if they have any messages and magic, they do! It's pretty funky, and easy to setup; *but just be aware of the potential overhead of having lots of users connected simultaneously. :)*

SignalR:
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Tutorial:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx

Comment: as i stated in the question, i don't want to use something premade. however, hopefully someone who hits this question will find your suggestion useful