# Notification for new message using js and asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, notifications

I have simple blog.

This is my model:

```
public class Post
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual bool Published { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime PostedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
public class Comment
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual string CommentText { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

}
public class Category
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

I want to show new user comments and new registered user as notification in my admin panel like SO:

[image]

I have seen some question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945959/) but I need sample source code.
i know about [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) but i don't need to implement it as realtime
How can I show new registered user, and new blog comment as notification in admin dashboard?

Thanks.

Comment: If you need real time feedback look into SignalR https://www.asp.net/signalr

Comment: @Greg no i dont want put SignalR in my project , dont need realtime i just want to show how much new comment inserted

Comment: Couldn't you just Count the number of comments in you Post?

Comment: @Greg i can count but spouse two comment inserted and i count it,know after it 3 comment inserted,when i use Count method it show my 5 but 3 comment are new!

Comment: You'll need to add a Date to the Comment entry. You can then filter either by current date or by the last time the user logged in. If you want to highlight unread comments you'll have to create a list referencing them in the user model.

Comment: @Greg can you put answer with code for me?? tnx

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a creation date to your `Comments`model.

```
public class Comment
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }    
   public virtual string CommentText { get; set; }    
   public virtual Category Category { get; set; }    
   public virtual DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }    
}
```

Example with dummy data

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var post = new Post
    {
        Comments = new List<Comment>
        {
            new Comment { CommentText = "Foo", CreationDate = DateTime.Today },
            new Comment { CommentText = "Bar", CreationDate = DateTime.Today },
            new Comment { CommentText = "Baz", CreationDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2) }
        }
    };

    //real value will be retrieved from database
    ViewBag.LastLogin = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);

    return View(post);
}
```

Comments filtered by date in the view

```
@model Post
<p>@Model.Comments.Count(c=> c.CreationDate >= ViewBag.LastLogin)</p>
```

Result will be 2

Comment: thank you for repaly but it show only new comment from past day, when new comment added in current day result would 3 and if new comment added again ,result will be 4 but actually result shoul be 2 and next time 1 and last time 1

Comment: Changed code to reflect filtering comments by last login, assuming this value gets updated after page refresh to current date.

Comment: If highlighting newer comments (since last login) isn't enough, you would have to create a reference table with all comments mapped to each user. Like that you can select unread comments by user.